# Сделать рабочим. Retrofit GSON JSON

Tags: android, json, kotlin

Нужно получить "firstname" в MainActivity(Log, Toast). Как реализовать? На простом примере крашится приложение.

```
{"firstname":"Bob"}
```

---

```
package json.usage

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val URL = "https://api.myjson.com/"
    private var irest: IRest? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()

        irest!!.getName().enqueue(object : Callback<Data> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Data>, response: Response<Data>) {
                Log.e("<<<<", ">>>>")
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Data>?, t: Throwable?) {
                TODO("not implemented")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

---

```
package json.usage

class Data {
    var firstname: String? = null
}
```

---

```
package json.usage

import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface IRest {
    @GET("bins/vytod/")
    fun getName(): Call<Data>
}
```

---

```
10-03 11:31:53.146 15549-15549/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: json.usage, PID: 15549
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{json.usage/json.usage.MainActivity}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                    Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
                                                       at json.usage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:28)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас же

```
private var irest: IRest? = null
```

а вы тут сразу в лоб лупите два восклицательных

```
irest!!.getName(). ...
```

Вот у вас и получается на выходе

```
kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
```

Comment: Требуется инициализация.